# Listview Custom Adapter with Button Tags

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have been experiencing a problem with my custom adapter and have located the problem solution. However I do not know how to go about it. I have researched and seen a few examples of a listview custom adapter at which buttons are given tags like `viewHolder.button.setTag(Tag)` and I understand what the tag does but I am unsure as to how to use it. My questions are: When I set the tag on a button, how does the application differentiate my buttons from another if all the tags are set the same? Also, say I have an onClick method in my custom adapter, how do I use the tag that I set to the button to identify the button that was clicked? I've kind of seen similar adapters on the internet but not exactly , a link to an example would be greatly appreciated also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unsure as to how to use it

`tag` is a mechanism to make your `views` remember something, that could be an `object` an `integer` a `string` or anything you like.

> My questions are: When I set the tag on a button, how does the
>   application differentiate my buttons from another if all the tags are
>   set the same?

i do not understand this question but i think if you notice that your `button` has a memory and it calls `tag` you can use it in a better way. if all of your `buttons` memory(tags) are the same so you can not use `tags` to distinguish the `buttons` you must use `ids`.

> say I have an onClick method in my custom adapter, how do I use the
>   tag that I set to the button to identify the button that was clicked?

you must set different `tags` for your `buttons` or grouped them logically and set different `tags` for each group then in your `onClick` method use the `tags` to identify your `buttons` group:

```
OnClickListener myButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Object obj = arg0.getTag();
    if(obj instanceOf groupOneTagObject){
       // do action for group 1
    }else if(obj instanceOf groupTwoTagObject){
       // do action for group 2
    }

    }   
});
```